# Best possible way to prevent Elapsed event of timer in windows service from firing till one cycle has completed

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I have a windows service which has a timer reading interval from configuration.

DipRedipServiceTimer_Elapsed event is called after 1000 miliseconds on first run of service. Code written in this method must be executed before running next cycle of this timer. however, i have seen DipRedipServiceTimer_Elapsed event firing even when the first cycle has not yet completed. this results is two threads working on same piece of code and some very horrible issues. How can i prevent this from happening ? Please suggest.

```
partial class DIPREDIPServiceHost : ServiceBase
{
    #region Private Fields
    /// <summary>
    /// Timer for polling job pool on timely basis 
    /// </summary>
    private Timer DipRedipServiceTimer;                                   
    #endregion
    public DIPREDIPServiceHost()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {                    
        DipRedipServiceTimer = new Timer();
        DipRedipServiceTimer.Enabled = true;            
        DipRedipServiceTimer.Interval = 1000;
        DipRedipServiceTimer.AutoReset = false; 
        DipRedipServiceTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(DipRedipServiceTimer_Elapsed);                        
    }
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (DipRedipServiceTimer != null)
        {
            DipRedipServiceTimer.Enabled = false;
            DipRedipServiceTimer.Stop();
            DipRedipServiceTimer = null;
        }
    }
    #region "Timer Elapsed Event"
    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the Elapsed event of the timer control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    void DipRedipServiceTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //disable timers as at a given time only one thread should process dip/redip. 
        DipRedipServiceTimer.Stop();
        DipRedipServiceTimer.AutoReset = false;
        DipRedipServiceTimer.Enabled = false;
        try
        {
            IDipRedipController controller = new DipRedipController();
            try
            {
                DipRedipConfiguration config = controller.GetDipRedipConfiguration();
                // In case configuration has been retrieved, set timer defined.
                if (config != null)
                {
                    //set timer interval after reading from config file.
                    DipRedipServiceTimer.Interval = config.FileGenerationInterval * 60000;
                    controller.dipRedipConfiguration = config;
                    LoggingHelper.LogMessage(String.Format("Dip Service timer initialized at {0}", DateTime.UtcNow), Source.EDiscDIPREDIPService, LogCategory.Exception);
                    //Process Dip
                    bool dipSuccess = controller.ProcessDIP();
                    //Process Re-Dip
                    bool redipSuccess = controller.ProcessREDIP();
                    //Enable timers for next cycle
                    LoggingHelper.LogMessage(String.Format("Dip Service timer completed at {0}", DateTime.UtcNow), Source.EDiscDIPREDIPService, LogCategory.Exception);
                }
                // In case configuration is null, get the default timer defined in App.Config file.
                else
                {
                    int interval = 0;
                    int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("DefaultTimerValue"), out interval);
                    DipRedipServiceTimer.Interval = interval * 60000;
                    LoggingHelper.LogWarning("Configuration for Dip/Redip could not be fetched from database.", Source.FileImportService, LogCategory.Exception);
                }                    
                DipRedipServiceTimer.Enabled = true;
                DipRedipServiceTimer.Start(); 
            }
            catch (FaultException ex)
            {
                LoggingHelper.LogException("Exception Occured in DipRedipServiceTimer_Elapsed method of Dip/Redip Window Service", ex, Source.EDiscDIPREDIPService);                    
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LoggingHelper.LogException("Exception Occured in the DipRedip Service Host Window Service", ex, Source.EDiscDIPREDIPService);               
        }
     }
    #endregion                 
}
```

Comment: You are properly disabling the timer at the beginning of your handler, so it won't fire again until you re-enable it. Are you sure that this is what really happens?

Comment: Yes i have verified it from Threads window inside debugger. One thread is executing DipRedipServiceTimer_Elapsed and second thread is executing controller.ProcessDIP() function.

Comment: You set AutoReset to false so it is not the standard problem.  One problem is OnStop(), it doesn't check if the Elapsed event handler is running and doesn't wait until it is complete.  So quickly stopping and starting the service is going to cause this problem.  Also note the NullReferenceException you can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following link 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval.aspx

describes behaviour of setting the interval again. I was setting interval from config before doing any processing thereby causing timer to reset and fir elaspsed event as per the documentation.

**Fix** :- I am setting interval after processing is done. This resets the timer and elapsed event will fire after configured interval. Also following lines of code are no more needed

```
    DipRedipServiceTimer.Stop();
    DipRedipServiceTimer.AutoReset = false;
    DipRedipServiceTimer.Enabled = false;
```

because autoreset is set to false while initializing the timer.

```
#region "Timer Elapsed Event"
    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the Elapsed event of the timer control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    void DipRedipServiceTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {                
            IDipRedipController controller = new DipRedipController();
            try
            {
                DipRedipConfiguration config = controller.GetDipRedipConfiguration();                    
                if (config != null)
                {
                    //set timer interval after reading from config file.                        
                    controller.dipRedipConfiguration = config;
                    LoggingHelper.LogMessage(String.Format("Dip Service timer initialized at {0}", DateTime.UtcNow), Source.EDiscDIPREDIPService, LogCategory.Exception);
                    //Process Dip
                    bool dipSuccess = controller.ProcessDIP();
                    //Process Re-Dip
                    bool redipSuccess = controller.ProcessREDIP();
                    // In case configuration has been retrieved, set timer defined.
                    DipRedipServiceTimer.Interval = config.FileGenerationInterval * 60000;
                    //Enable timers for next cycle
                    LoggingHelper.LogMessage(String.Format("Dip Service timer completed at {0}", DateTime.UtcNow), Source.EDiscDIPREDIPService, LogCategory.Exception);
                }
                // In case configuration is null, get the default timer defined in App.Config file.
                else
                {
                    int interval = 0;
                    int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("DefaultTimerValue"), out interval);
                    DipRedipServiceTimer.Interval = interval * 60000;
                    LoggingHelper.LogWarning("Configuration for Dip/Redip could not be fetched from database.", Source.EDiscDIPREDIPService, LogCategory.Exception);
                }                                        
                DipRedipServiceTimer.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LoggingHelper.LogException("Exception Occured in DipRedipServiceTimer_Elapsed method of Dip/Redip Window Service", ex, Source.EDiscDIPREDIPService);                    
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LoggingHelper.LogException("Exception Occured in the DipRedip Service Host Window Service", ex, Source.EDiscDIPREDIPService);               
        }
     }
    #endregion
```